# Count values of sublists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

Let's say I have a list of lists in Python where each element represents a day and how many products are available in a shop:

```py
l = [
    [a, a, a, b, c],
    [a, a, b, b, c],
    [a, b, b, c, c]
]
```

I would like to create a summary that shows:

```
Day 1: a:3, b:1, c:1 
Day 2: a:2, b:2, c:1 
Day 3: a:1, b:2, c:2
```

I need it in a format that I can then chart the availability of products over time.

I've tried this:

```py
from collections import Counter
    
Counter(x for sublist in l for x in sublist)
```

But that counts the elements up across all lists rather than returning the result for each sublist.

Thanks everyone, here's the final solution including the charting:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {i:Counter(sublist) for i, sublist in enumerate(l, start=1)}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()
df = df.melt('index', var_name='product',  value_name='vals')
df['product'] = df['product'].map({'A': 'a', 'B': 'b','C': 'c','D': 'd'})
sns.lineplot(x="index", y="vals", hue='product', data=df)
```

Comment: Try this `[Counter(sublist) for sublist in l]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `dict comprehension`:

```
>>> {f'Day {i}': Counter(sublist) for i, sublist in enumerate(l, start=1)}
{'Day 1': Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}),
 'Day 2': Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}),
 'Day 3': Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2})}
```

Comment: Nice answser.  Note that the `Counter` objects can be removed from the result, each replaced by a `dict`, by changing `Counter(sublist)` to `dict(Counter(sublist))`, which I expect would often be preferred.

Comment: @Steve True, however I feel there are very few situations where counting is involved, dict should be preferred over Counter. Unless it relies on something regarding missing keys.

Comment: You could be right.  Not having an in-depth knowledge of the `Counter` class, I'd prefer to play it safe and get rid of its use if a `dict` is all I need.  Even if I had expert knowledge of the `Counter` object's behavior, another programmer could come along later who lacks that knowledge.  At that point, I see a distinct advantage in stripping the use of `Counter` from the final result.  My thought was that others would likely see this as an advantage as well, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Simpler and ugly Version ofc you can change according to your need

```
>>> for i in l:
...     x=Counter(i)
...     print(x['a'],'a')
...     print(x['b'],'b')
...     print(x['c'],'c')
```

you can retrive index by enumerating the list

Comment: This doesn't produce a result that satisfies the stated requirement: "in a format that I can then chart the availability of products over time".